# Have two generations of one family ever won a medal at the same Olympics?

Tags: trivia, history, records, olympics, awards

[Nino Salukvadze and her son Tsotne Machavariani](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/olympics-fourth-place-medal/rio-will-feature-first-ever-mother-son-duo-at-olympic-games-175559044.html) have both qualified for Rio 2016 Olympic games.

Has it ever happened in the past that two generations of the same family have won a medal in the same Olympics? (including both winter and summer Olympics)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, here's an example: [Alfred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Swahn) and his father [Oscar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Swahn) Swahn (Sweden) - [1912, shooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_at_the_1912_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men's_100_metre_team_running_deer,_single_shots), team gold.

Oscar is particularly interesting, "At 64 years of age, he became the oldest gold medalist ever, which he still remains up to today."